# How to mount a specific hadoop folder via NFS gateway

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I am trying to setup a NFS Gateway for my hadoop cluster following steps mentioned in this nice [guide](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.2.8/bk_hdfs_nfs_gateway/content/hdfs-nfs-gateway-user-guide.html). I have followed steps [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.2.8/bk_hdfs_nfs_gateway/content/hdfs-nfs-gateway-user-guide.html). I am able to mount the `/` using command mentioned in the doc:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock $server:/ $mount_point
```

But I want to mount a folder present in my HDFS like this:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock $server:/$dir $mount_point
```

But this gives following error from mount command:

> mount.nfs: mounting 10.33.37.220:/dir failed, reason given by server:
>
> No such file or directory

and in NFS gateway, following log appears:

> 18/04/05 15:14:43 INFO mount.RpcProgramMountd: Path /dir is not shared.

I have also trying adding following line in `/etc/exports`

```
saurabh@0001:~$ cat /etc/exports
/whatsappData 10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync)
```

How can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

From Hadoop [docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html), I found there is one config Export point: `nfs.export.point`

This can specify the NFS export point of HDFS. Exactly one export point is supported. Full path is required when configuring the export point. By default, the export point is the root directory `/`.

So setting following solved my issue:

```
<property>
  <name>nfs.export.point</name>
  <value>/dir</value>
</property>
```